# Parent's Reference to Child Window Breaks upon Child Form Submit

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have an application containing a JavaScript view model controlling it.

The application launches a new window with (`window.open()`) and assigns `click` event listeners to buttons in the new window. New window contains a form, which when submitted, causes an `unload` event on its window, and thus breaking access to it from the parent window.

How can the parent's reference to this new window persist or reinstate, when the window 'unloads' and a form submits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not keep that reference. However if you are trying to access some kind of values you may look into [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

You can also try to reinstate the reference by attaching an event listener to the "unload" event. When the event occurs close the current "parent" window, and make the "submit" script point to the parent window. Once opened you can re-open the child window from there.

**Update**

Cross-window javascript is a messy subject. I advise taking the first approach if it's applicable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, not all browsers allow to regain access to a window by name even if you provide it. But I'd still try to use distinct window names with `window.open`.

When trying to regain access to it - just do a window.open without url - maybe `javascript:void(0)` as address (so the window doesn't navigate away), it should be the same window as long as you use the same id.

it's pretty hacky though